# Simple way to create Python Dashboard

Tags: python, dashboard

I have a simple business case - creating online dashboard. No graphs, not plots, no visuals, just simple table.
Is there any simple way, to create this dashboard WITHOUT any django knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/

The quickstart should be enough to get you going. It's very lightweight and a lot easier to use compared to Django for such an easy use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you,With Dash, we can create interactive web-based dashboards with pure Python

https://alysivji.github.io/reactive-dashboards-with-dash.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an open-source framework called [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) that can convert Python code in Jupyter Notebook into a web application. It can be a dashboard. The workflow is as follows:

- create a Python notebook,
- add a YAML header that tells Mercury how to serve the notebook,
- publish notebook as a web app to the cloud,
- end-users can tweak widgets parameters and execute notebooks with new values.

I wrote the article describing [how to build a simple financial dashboard with 9 lines of Python code](https://mljar.com/blog/dashboard-python-jupyter-notebook/). You can check it for more details. Below are presented notebook + YAML header and the resulting web dashboard.

### The Python notebook

[image: Python notebook]

### The YAML header

```yaml
---
title: Finance dashboard
description: Dashboard with financial data
show-code: False
params:
    ticker: 
        input: select
        value: TSLA
        label: Select ticker
        choices: [TSLA, COIN, MSFT, PLTR, SNOW, NFLX]
---
```

### The web app dashboard from Python notebook

[image: python dashboard]